# CS50 llamas lab I don't know how to solve it

Tags: cs50

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int start ;
do
{
start = get_int("start size: ");
}
while (start < 9);

```
int end;
do
{
    end = get_int("end size: ");
}
while (end < start);

int year = 0;
do
{
    start = start + (start / 3) - (start / 4);//calculate number of years untile we reach thresholㅇ
    **year++;**
}
while (start < end);

printf("Years: %i", year);
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKXZD.png)
:( handles same starting and ending sizes
expected "Years: 0", not "Years: 1"

i think year++ is the problem i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Please read the tag excerpt for [tag:cs50] as it states; `Code questions pertaining to Harvard's self-study introductory. It is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to additionally tag with C or Python. Also consider using the spin-off https://cs50.stackexchange.com/`. Therefore, please tag your question appropriately or consider the appropriate cs50.se site

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried [debugging your program yourself](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/11107541)? Doing some debugging can help you provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the `do` loop will execute the body and *then* test the condition (in the `while`). When `start` and `end` are both 100, `year` will be incremented before it evaluates the `while` condition. Since program needs to compare `start` and `end` *before* it increments `year`, a simple `while` loop is appropriate.